# Saving linked list internal iterator

Tags: c, linked-list

I have some ADT which is based on a linked list.
Many of my functions use the following algorithm to find some particular list element:

```
currentElement = listGetFirst(list)
while (currentElement != neededElement)
{
currentElement = listGetNext(list);
}
```

Now i want to write 2 functions for saving internal iterator and restoring it back, like this:

```
void listSaveIterator(List list, ListElement *iterator)
{
    *iterator = listGetCurrent(list);
}

void listRestore(List list, ListElement iterator)
{
    ListElement element = listGetFirst(list);
    while (element != NULL)
    {
        if (element == iterator)
        {
            return;
        }
        element = listGetNext(list);
    }
}
```

Will this work?
Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you mean to have a call to listSaveIterator before the return in listRestore?

Comment: Yes, I want to write 2 functions for saving the iterator and restoring it back.
The problem is that i can't change the linked list ADC, and these function should be outside of that "hidden" to me implementation of the linked list.

Comment: I don't get the listRestore.  Why doesn't it return an interator?

Comment: Because i dont need to return anything, just set the iterator...

Comment: But you aren't setting the iterator.  You are just setting the local variable element and then exiting.

Comment: You should post also the definition of both List and ListIterator. For what I see from the first snippet you can use listGetCurrent to traverse the list, and if list is of type List, then a list must have some internal state that keeps the current position in the traversal. You want to save and then restore that, but we need to know either the internal structure of List or a the set of functions that can access a List instance.